# Problem in integrating facebook with android

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating my Android app with facebook for that I have used Facebook SDK .
I have followed steps given in [Link](http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/).

But I am not getting on thing when I use Keytool cmd on my terminal it asks me a keystore password .what is it?
Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That passsword should be "android", when you try to create the signature with the debug key.
This is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode).

Otherwise you have to use a password that your created for your keystore. Since you don't seem to know about that, try the "android" pass.

Comment: Thanks alextsc it seems to work but not exactly as I was willing .After giving keystore password "passsword"  it shows me many character like '�?�=�0�Ϋ����?���;��|T�)��ev9��1ˀ*�lө�=����|�r���zc���-  l<w���*��)ly|�+ўnO����`���ak%��q��%c#�Y��X�              ���0
                                                                                                           ����r  I am not getting whether it is right or not Please Help

Comment: Mh sounds strange. Please make sure you have OpenSSL installed correctly and also that it is in your PATH. (If you are not sure about this: Workaround, copy the openssl binary to the folder with your keytool executable, and delete after you are finished). The correct result should be something like "ab123XyzA+xyZ0l12Klm6jklMNop=" (fictive result from my head).

Comment: Also make sure that you have the whole command in one line, if you copy it for example from the link you provided you will have line breaks. Copy the command into a texteditor and remove all line breaks. Then copy it from there to your command line.